# Sumar columna total y agrupar por mes en mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Cómo hago para sumar la columna total y agrupar  por la columna `mes`, pero que no me sume cuando el `id_orden` sea repetido (218), ya intente agruparlos por mes,y me queda así:
La suma del mes 5 es 10 y la suma del mes 1  da 240, y quiero que me de la suma del mes 1 sea  190 ya que el id_orden 218 esta repetido.

[image: tabla nysql]

Comment: dale un título más descriptivo, que si no no habrá quien lo encuentre :)

Answer (score 4):

Te propongo esta respuesta

```
select id_orden, mes, producto, sum(distinct total) as total
from ventas where id_orden not in(218) group by mes;
```

Y este es el resultado

```
+----------+-----+----------+-------+
| id_orden | mes | producto | total |
+----------+-----+----------+-------+
|      214 |   1 | reloj    |   140 |
|      210 |   5 | monitor  |    10 |
+----------+-----+----------+-------+
```

Comment: Gracias por responder,  pero quiero que el resultado final sea agrupado por mes o sea el mes 5  el total sea 10 y mes 1 total sea 150

Comment: @JuanDavidDelgadoJ te actualicé la respúesta

Comment: mmm al parecer esta bien, pero en la consulta excluiste el producto "celular" con el id_orden "2190",  el que debería excluir es UNO de los dos producto  repeditos (id_orden:218) asi que el total del mes 1 debe ser 190. espero que me ayudes nuevamente.  gracias

Comment: espero si logro formar la respuesta te lo posteo @JuanDavidDelgadoJ

Answer (score 0):

Quizás te funcione:

```
SELECT id_orden, mes, producto, sum(total) as total
       FROM ventas 
       WHERE id_order in(SELECT DISTINCT id_order FROM ventas)
       GROUP BY mes;
```

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Esta fue mi solución:

```
SELECT id_orden ,
       fecha_transaccion, 
       month(fecha_transaccion) AS MES ,
       producto,sum(total) 
FROM (
      SELECT id_orden ,
             fecha_transaccion, 
             month(fecha_transaccion) AS MES ,
             producto,total 
      FROM `ingresos_ecommerce`  
      WHERE email_destino = "xxx@gmail.com" AND 
            ING.tipo = "virtual" 
      GROUP BY id_orden, month(fecha_transaccion)
     ) 
AS TAB GROUP BY month(fecha_transaccion)
```